# how to override default -fx-focus-color css property in javafx?

Tags: css, javafx

[image]I want to style my JavaFX application by overriding default css theme.

I am using few css attributes,

The attributes are

```
-fx-focus-color: #C70039;
-fx-accent: #C70039;
```

-fx-accent work well, but -fx-focus-color does not override the default blue color. Rather it overlaps it and produces an undesired grey like color.

I am using Scene Builder to load css stylesheet.

Please suggest how to get the desired result i.e. red focus color?

Update: As shown in image, complete datepicker is expected to have the red color. But just the datepicker button appears as expected. The date area does not appear as expected. Same result is observable with text field. I think this makes the issue more clear.

As for now I have overridden it from java code. And it works as expected.

Comment: looks okay for me (fx11) - Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @kleopatra, when trying to take screenshot, the focus is moving out of the window. So, currently can not show you exact issue. I will try to run it in a virtual box, and update screen shot here soon. Thanks for reply.

Comment: just change those two colors in isolation, nothing else - if you don't see the issue then, the reason is somewhere else, maybe some derived color somewhere?

Comment: I overrided it from java code. Now the border appears to whole textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As for now I have overridden it from java code and it works as expected.

Comment: glad that you found a workaround for now :) In the longer run it pays off to understand _why_ it's not working the other way as it should

Comment: Sure, I will figure it out in week ends with some project from scratch. Thank you so much kleopatra